# Github commit/push rule, check two files have same list of variables

Tags: git, github, ballerina

I have two files in my Github repo written in [Ballerina](https://ballerina.io/) language.
Namely, `ballerina.conf` and `ballerina.conf.example` which are used to store similar list of configuration variables.

In these files I keep the ACTUAL user credentials (which are used to connect to several systems) in `ballerina.conf` file.
But when committing the project to GitHub I want to commit only the `ballerina.conf.example` file. I can omit the `ballerina.conf` file in `.gitignore` file.

My question is, users may forget sometimes to include the same variable in both `ballerina.conf` and `ballerina.conf.example` files.

```
ballerina.conf -> DB_USERNAME = 'cseuser'  
ballerina.conf.example -> DB_USERNAME = '[dbusername]'
```

Is there a way to enforce a rule in Github to compare these two files upon commit/push that the newly introduced variable is in both of the files?

e.g. If the user has introduced a variable ONLY in `ballerina.conf` file, I want to reject the commit/push saying the reason to the user. I.e. add the same variable to `ballerina.conf.example` with dummy value as well.

Comment: I question your workflow which results in each user's push potentially assigning a new database username.  Maybe this file should not even be versioned, or if it is, then folks should not be including it when they commit and push.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

Just found out that ballerina language itself provides a way to encrypt the password using command `ballerina encrypt`.

e.g. encrypt value: 1234

Following is the sample output I have tried.

```
$ballerina encrypt 
Enter value:

Enter secret: 

Re-enter secret to verify:

Add the following to the runtime config:
@encrypted:{DMTaGYeDc2B9SBJmy5ekUSsYW8TV1uipLPTofy4zjr2Ke8eZ7khQbyDnKnNJ1kZm}

Or add to the runtime command line:
-e<param>=@encrypted:{DMTaGYeDc2B9SBJmy5ekUSsYW8TV1uipLPTofy4zjr2Ke8eZ7khQbyDnKnNJ1kZm}
```

I have used the encrypted value in my `ballerina.conf` as follows.

```
DB_USERNAME = "@encrypted:{l1WoT/u1YMX2+njesLjzKdpHXT7Vk03d830mjCFTSB+75aeohAO2AkEScotn7Wry}"
```

Hence no need to maintain a secondary file in Github.

### Update

When running the ballerina service ballerina will ask to enter the secret you have used to encrypt the passwords in ballerina.conf file.

```
$ballerina run integrator/
ballerina: enter secret for config value decryption: 
<type your encryption password here (not visible), 1234>

ballerina: started HTTP/WS endpoint 0.0.0.0:3001


2019-03-03 12:44:25,999 INFO  [integrator:0.0.0] - service started
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the way to storing passwords rather than storing them as plaintext.

Comment: I believe that publishing even encrypted passwords is wrong (e.g. if you publish a real encrypted password, not a fake one). An eventual attacker might try to break them offline (e.g. by running a cluster of GPU extended computers). Any password data is a serious matter, related to privacy. I really believe you need to *transform* your `ballerina.conf` into some `ballerina.conf.example`, see my answer for more.

Comment: Yes agree with @BasileStarynkevitch to transform `ballerina.conf` into some `ballerina.conf.example` file before committing in Github. 
Yes @Rajith when this ballerina service and `ballerina.conf` file deployed in servers better to encrypt password (shown below) and store it in `ballerina.conf` instead of storing just as plain text.

Comment: I will go ahead with adding dummy encrypted values (not real ones) in `ballerina.conf` file to Github so that next developers will have an idea on how to use these variables in `ballerina.conf` file using ballerina encryption mechanism. So that the development and deployment teams all together will have a uniform idea when looking at the existing Github repo.
I'm selecting this as the answer since Ballerina language has provided an encrypting mechanism build into the language. For any other project going forward I will select @BasileStarynkevitch answer as my first choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility might be to have some [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) or other transforming script which replaces the real credentials by fake ones, e.g. create some `ballerina.conf.example` from an existing (but not `git commit`-ed, so `.gitignore`-d) `ballerina.conf` one.

And that transforming script could even be some [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) (probably a pre-commit one) to ensure it is run automatically.

> If the user has introduced a variable ONLY in ballerina.conf file, I want to reject the commit/push saying the reason to the user.

That is what git hooks are for.

Beware however that if you publish by `git` some personal information about real European citizens, you may be concerned by the European [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation). But I am not a lawyer (but an European citizen happy of the existence of that GDPR), but you might need one.

If you *develop* some application which also manage passwords, I recommend putting these encrypted passwords in some *separate* file, different of the place keeping user information. The current Unix way of having *separate* `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files could be inspirational (and Apache is doing similar things with its [htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html)). See for example [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) and [shadow(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html). You'll never `git` publish your own equivalent of `shadow` data. FWIW, I am doing similar things in my [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) GPLv3+ project (`git`-kept file [contributors_BM](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/contributors_BM) describing users vs `.gitignore`-d file `passwords_BM` holding encrypted passwords).

PS. Don't publish even encrypted, but real, password data. A determined hacker might use computer resources you don't even dream of to break that.

Comment: Yes we don't have any data of EU citizens committed to Github. These are internal system integration password. Yes, agree with you, not to even publish encrypted real passwords. Will look into git hooks in details. (Y)